# SQL Server Openrowset only imports 2000 rows from large excel (.xls) file

Tags: sql-server, excel, openrowset

I have a large excel files (about 10MB) containing 60000 rows of datas.
I would like to import all these rows into SQL Server database.
Assuming the filepath is C:\file.xls, my query would be :

```
SELECT * INTO ImportedExcel FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0',
'Excel 8.0;Database=C:\file.xls', 'SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]')
```

The process ran well but only imported 2000 rows instead of 60000.
Please help me to solve this problem. Thanks.

Comment: Have you done some research? What has that turned up?

Comment: IIRC, this is a limitation of the Jet provider under certain circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an idea..  Why not commit every 500 or so transactions?

We all know there is a limitation of 65,530 records in Excel, but I seriously doubt you are hitting that ceiling.

```
DECLARE @SelCount INT
-- Initialize the select count 
SET @SelCount = 0
SET @SelCount = @SelCount + 1

SELECT * INTO ImportedExcel FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0',
'Excel 8.0;Database=C:\file.xls', 'SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]') 

      -- Commit every 500 records and start a new transaction 
      IF @SelCount % 500 = 0
        BEGIN
            COMMIT TRANSACTION
            BEGIN TRANSACTION
        END
  END

IF @SelCount % 500 <> 0
  BEGIN
      COMMIT TRANSACTION
  END
GO
```

Answer (score -1):

So, the process "ran well" but gave the wrong answer and reported no error.  Time to try something else, wouldn't you say?

Maybe this kind of thing can be made to work.  Maybe there some abracadabra setting that turns off the row limit.  If so, someone here will know.  My advice is to get off that train before it wrecks with you in it.

Using anything you like -- VBA, Perl, by hand -- have Excel write out the data to a (preferably) tab-delimited file.  "Save as ..." is pretty safe; I don't remember a time Excel saved *part* of a sheet to a text file.  Then import the file with BCP or BULK INSERT.

It's a little more work initially, but it's robust, and will save you eyeballing the results of an undependable technology.